# Detect nuw and nsw in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

Please let me know how to detect the presence of instructions with nsw and nuw flags set on them in the LLVM IR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OverflowingBinaryOperator` has the `hasNoUnsignedWrap` and `hasNoSignedWrap` predicates for this purpose.

More specifically, given some instruction `ii`:

```
   if (OverflowingBinaryOperator *op = dyn_cast<OverflowingBinaryOperator>(ii)) {
       if (op->hasNoUnsignedWrap())
           errs() << "  has nuw\n";
       else if (op->hasNoSignedWrap())
           errs() << "  has nsw\n";
       }
   }
```